# Specific table case: common scroll for table column cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I want to make a common scroll for all the cells from a certain column, but i don't want to make multiple iterations for this to happen (for each first, second and third column), something similar to what I've done in this [pen](https://codepen.io/Dragosb/pen/ZgEryw)

I do not wish to keep the elements segregated by columns like in the codepen example and I am open to using flexbox or anything.

Preferring to avoid using `<table>` though.

Comment: What does multiple iterations mean? Like, if you only want the scroll to happen for a certain column, why would you need to mess with other columns? Also, what does "segregated by columns" mean?

Comment: Could you explain What does "segregated by columns" mean?

Comment: I just want to add the content in the cells as i receive them, not to split them by first, second and third column like in the pen.